# Retrieve row where sum of column is greater than other column of different table

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have two database tables.

First table:

```
| ID  |  Sub-Name |  Marks
| 01  |  french   |  50
| 01  |  russian  |  50
| 02  |  french   |  30
| 02  |  russian  |  50
| 03  |  french   |  20
| 03  |  russian  |  30
```

Second table:

```
|  ID | Stu-name | passing_marks
|  01 | abc      | 90
|  02 | xyz      | 90
|  03 | mno      | 90
```

I want to get the names of students whose collective marks of French and Russian are greater the `passing_marks` of table2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please , First declare `primarykey` and `foreignkey` relation with table with proper `table name`

Here I take  1st named `detail` and second table name is `student`

```
SELECT student.ID, student.Stu_name, detail.collective
FROM student
JOIN  
(
   SELECT ID, SUM(Marks) AS collective
   FROM detail GROUP BY ID
) detail
ON student.ID = detail.ID
AND detail.collective> student.passing_marks;
```

Comment: Hi, what if I do not need to output  SUM(detail.Marks)?

Comment: edited : if you don't want to print total in output then just remove `detail.collective` from select

Answer (score 0):

Try to join with sub-query like this:

```
SELECT t2.ID, t2.Stu_name, t1.Total 
FROM Table2 t2
JOIN  
(
   SELECT ID, SUM(Marks) AS Total
   FROM Table1 GROUP BY ID
) t1
ON t2.ID = t1.ID
AND t1.Total > t2.passing_marks;
```

Output:

```
| ID | STU_NAME | TOTAL |
-------------------------
|  1 |      abc |   100 |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61aa2/6)